# \n changes to \\n after reading csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, newline

I am reading a file that has `\n` as a new line character. But when I read it using pandas, it appears as `\\n`. How can I avoid this?

I tried both pandas and python csv but nothing worked

Comment: Please *show* what you are doing and what result you are getting. Copy relevant code/commands/data and paste to your question *as text*.

Comment: It's not changing, that's just the way Python shows it.

Comment: If the linked duplicates _aren't_ on-point, please [edit] your question to include enough technical details to clearly distinguish your question from the preexisting ones, and @-notify me when that edit is complete.

Answer (score 0):

in pandas, you can set lineterminator to '\n' and that should work. Alternatively, you can use the csv module in python to read your csv file as follows :

```
import csv
with open(filepath, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\n')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```